# NSFetchedResultsController change tracking

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I know that an `NSFetchedResultsController` tracks changes from a bg context (i.e. merge changes).

Does it also track changes to the main context?

i.e. if I have an `NSFetchedResultsController` fetching `Person` objects and I use an "Edit Person" view to change the actual `Person` that is passed in will the Controller see the change?

Comment: The controller will see the change, even if it is not yet persistant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fetched results controller tracks *only* changes from its own context. If you save 
changes on a background context and then merge the changes to the main context, the FRC
on the main context will see these changes (normally, see below). But saying that it *"tracks changes from a bg context"* is misleading.

Whether the FRC sees non-persistent changes, depends on the setting of `includesPendingChanges` in the fetch request. By default, this value is `YES`, *unless*
you set the value of `resultType` to `NSDictionaryResultType`. In that case, the FRC returns
only the state of the persistent store, and change tracking does not work at all.